# In Flask, how can I redirect to a profile being clicked?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am very new to Flask. I have a mysql database and a template. Let's say I have 3 images

```
 <a href="#"><div><img src= pathOfImage id="profile1"/></div></a>
 <a href="#"><div><img src= pathOfImage id="profile2"/></div></a>
 <a href="#"><div><img src= pathOfImage id="profile3"/></div></a>
```

The id of each image (profile1,profile2,profile3) is the primary key of the some tables in the database. What I want to do is to find the values of the corresponding attributes of that tuple by using the primary key. Then, load that those values to the template from the tuples.

And, I have the following code in Python:

```
 from flask import *
 @app.route("/")
 def index():
 return render_template("index.html")

 @app.route('/experts')
 def route1():
    return render_template("experts.html", data=data)
```

The snippet of HTML code I gave above is in expert.html. I almost of SQL query that was not listed above, data on the second parameter in render_template in route1() is the SQL tuple, which generate all these images and the ID.

I have tried to put a button next to the images, and give id to the button instead. Then, pass the id to the python script as a variable using Ajax, and get the SQL tuple.

However, this isn't the hard part. The hard part is making the new route and loading the content. I have tried make a new route using "app.route" and pass the data into the second parameter of render_template. But, it didn't redirect to a new profile, and the method was called before I even click on the profile.

previously, I used button to retrieve the id:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}"> <button id='1'>Button1</button></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}"><button id='2'>Button2</button></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}"><button id='3'>Button3</button></a>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function(event) {
       var the_id = event.target.id;
       $.ajax({
       url: "/get_id",
       type: "get",
       data: {the_id: the_id},
       success: function(response) {

      },
       error: function(xhr) {

    }
   });           
})});
</script>
```

and, I used these to generate a new template:

```
 import flask
 from flask import *
 from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

 @app.route("/")
 def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

 @app.route('/experts')
 def route1():
      return render_template("experts.html", data=data)

 @app.route('/get_id')
 @app.route('/profile')
 def route2():
      button_id '"' + flask.request.args.get('the_id') + '"'
      //some code here to get the tuples that I need "client_info" and 
      //"skill_info" variable below
      return render_template("profile.html", client_info=client_info, 
      skill_info=skill_info)
```

Hope someone would give a fresh start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show us the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, one second. I will update it

Comment: @KlausD. Just updated

Comment: I dont understand at all what your question is ... or what any of this has to do with pycharm ...

Comment: @joran, just ignore what I previously have. if I have 3 profile pictures, and click on one of them, I want it to redirect to that profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing info by ajax you can pass it through the route url.

### experts.html

```
<a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}/profile1"><div><img src="pathOfImage"></div></a>
<a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}/profile2"><div><img src="pathOfImage"></div></a>
<a href="{{ url_for('route2') }}/profile3"><div><img src="pathOfImage"></div></a>
```

### flask routes

```
import flask
from flask import *
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/experts')
def route1():
    return render_template("experts.html", data=data)

@app.route('/profile/<id>')
def route2(id):
    # id variable contains user profile id string as per user click
    # depending on id set variables client_info and skill_info and render
    return render_template("profile.html", client_info=client_info, skill_info=skill_info)
```

Comment: The ID is not not shown of each div in experts.html

Comment: With above code visiting experts.html, you should see 3 images and clicking any image will redirect you to /profile/<id> url and display that specific profile.

Is that not what you require?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
<a href="/profile?the_profile={{ profile.id }}"><img src="{{profile.img}}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

...I guess? maybe?

Comment: thanks I will try to run it and let you know if it works